# How should a C++ api be laid out?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, c-preprocessor, header-files, include-path

Imagining I'm publishing a C++ library with its include files in a folder named `api`.

```
// file: api/mylib/fwd/foo.h
inline int mylib_foo();

// file: api/mylib/impl/foo.h
inline int mylib_foo() { return 42; }
```

In the context of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388947/is-there-any-standard-requirement-for-c-include-lookup), is it advisable for library builders to always use the 'full path' to their own (api) include files?

```
// file: api/mylib/all.h
#include "mylib/fwd/foo.h" // as opposed to "fwd/foo.h"
#include "mylib/impl/foo.h" // as opposed to "impl/foo.h"
```

Or could it be acceptable to rely on the fact that the preprocessor 'often' searches the including folder first?

If you don't want to add `/home/xtofl/libs/mylib/api` to the compiler's include path but rather ... `#include "/home/xtofl/libs/mylib/api/mylib/all.h"`, or even just put mylib next to the client code.

```
// file: api/mylib/all.h
#include "fwd/foo.h"
#include "impl/foo.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

N.B. this is nothing to do with how the project is laid out (as the title of your question says), because in all cases you are assuming that the headers are in a sub-directory called `fwd`. The question is about what kind of `#include` directives to use *given a particular layout*. Anyway ...

> In the context of this question, is it advisable for library builders to always use the 'full path' to their own (api) include files?

```
// file: api/mylib/all.h
#include "mylib/fwd/foo.h" // as opposed to "fwd/foo.h"
#include "mylib/impl/foo.h" // as opposed to "impl/foo.h"
```

That assumes that the including code adds the `api` dir to its search paths, and you already mentioned two ways that assumption can fail:

> If you don't want to add `/home/xtofl/libs/mylib/api` to the compiler's include path but rather ... `#include "/home/xtofl/libs/mylib/api/mylib/all.h"`, or even just put `mylib` next to the client code.

So IMHO this is better:

> Or could it be acceptable to rely on the fact that the preprocessor 'often' searches the including folder first?

Yes, I think it's better to rely on that, and do:

```
// file: api/mylib/all.h
#include "fwd/foo.h"
#include "impl/foo.h"
```

That handles the case where `api` is in the search path, and the case where it's not, and the case where `mylib` isn't in a directory called `mylib` at all.

It relies on the implementation-defined rule that searching for headers included with `#include "..."` starts in the including file's directory, but that is common to all compilers I know, and is a safer assumption than the other assumptions about where the files are installed.

Comment: Should the library even use quoted includes?  Looking at Boost and Qt, they don't.  You always have to specify the include path, or install them to the 'usual places'.